# Custom function to find mode in R not working

Tags: r, magrittr

I wanted to define a function in R to find out the mode of a vector. I made a simple one which is shown below:

```
modeFinder <- function(par) {
  modeTable <- par %>% table() %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% data.frame()
  modeVal <- modeTable$Var1[1] %>% as.character()
  return(modeVal)
}
```

However, when I use this function it always returns empty values. I actually wanted to use this for my summarize function but it doesn't work. I tried to diagnose by segregating the steps like below and it works completely fine that way!

```
# let's assume a vector "Vic" with expected output "m"
Vic <- c(rep("m", 3), rep("g", 2))
temp <- Vic %>% table() %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% data.frame()
temp2 <- temp$Var1[1] %>% as.character()
```

I just can't understand why the custom function is not working while the same code is working outside the function.

I would really appreciate any solution to this. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I think my question is not clear to some. I just want to know what the problem is in my custom function. I am not looking for any inbuilt function or an alternative to this.

Comment: Could you give an example vector `Vic` and associated expected output?

Comment: `Vic <- c(rep("m", 3), rep("g", 2))`

Output would be: 

"m" character

Comment: `Vic %>% table %>% sort(decreasing=TRUE) %>% as.data.frame %>% extract2(".") %>% extract(1) %>% as.character` seems to work, though it's kind of convoluted. This is assuming you have loaded magrittr. If performance matters, you'll want to look at some of these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode pipes can slow things down.

Comment: The set of R statements written below works fine. It's the first one, or the function, that isn't working for some reason. That is my question.

Comment: Try running the code you think works in a fresh R session with just magrittr loaded. It does not work, as far as I can see, since `temp` will have a column named `"."`, not `"Var1"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode)

Comment: it's not a duplicate, he doesn't want an alternative, he want to know why his code doesn't work

Comment: so your code doesn't work either way (in the function or outside), if you replace `$Var1[1]` by `[1,1]` it will run fine

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper - Thanks a lot. It works now. But it still doesn't answer my question. What was the problem in my function definition?

Comment: For me (and for Moody_Mudskipper) your code doesn't work. It doesn't work in the function, and it doesn't work out of the function. So the problem in your function definition is that is uses code that doesn't work. I think if you start a new R session and run your code outside of the function, you will also find that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Gregor, I think you guys need to use "." instead of "Var1". Or temp$.[1] instead of temp$Var1[1]. The table column name shows as Var1 in my R studio but as a "." for others.

Comment: Well, if I switch to `temp$.[1]` then the code works for me both inside the function and outside the function. I can't reproduce a case where there is a difference inside the function vs outside.

Comment: It is happening in my RStudio. I have also updated to the latest versions of both my R and RStudio. But still, I see "Var1" instead of "." and the function doesn't work while the same code outside works fine. That was my question: what is the reason behind this function not working fine?

Comment: We can't replicate your problem, so we can't tell you what it is. Are you starting in a fresh R session? Are you loading packages that override, say, the default `table` function? You reference RStudio... is the problem specific to working in RStudio or does it also happen if you use the R command line or the default R GUI?